# Read the third string only java

Tags: string, file, get, cpu-word

I have a file for example like this :

file.txt

Milano Tirana Paris

Madrid Istanbul Berlin

And I want to read just the third words of each line Paris and Berlin. I tried with substring but it won't work because the length changes. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading the whole line, tokenizing it by splitting it at whitespace, and return the index of the value you want.

Something like this:

```
package misc;

/**
 * CityParser demo
 * @author Michael
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420434/read-the-third-string-only-java/24420447#24420447
 * @since 6/25/2014 8:36 PM
 */
public class CityParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tokenIndex = 2;
        CityParser parser = new CityParser();
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println((String.format("line: '%s' tokenIndex: %d token: %s", args, tokenIndex, parser.getToken(arg, tokenIndex))));
        }
    }

    public String getToken(String line, int tokenIndex) {
        String token = null;
        if ((line != null) && (line.trim().length() > 0)) {
            String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            if ((tokens.length > 0)) {
                token = tokens[tokenIndex];
            }
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the character " ". So for every line, count two " "'s then record kbd.next() to get the word.